# Add items to .plist from and display in custom UITableViewCell

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uitableview, plist

I want to write data to multiple `NSMUtableArray`'s from the user pressing `IBAction`'s that then saves the time they pressed it, Location and os on, to a `.plist`. I then want to retrieve the data that was written in the plist and display it in a custom `UITableViewCell` that I have created. There are around 8 - 10 different labels in the cell. I have already made the plist file `history.plist` and there are a few things in there. I need the data to go in there. And to keep writing data there, such that after the data is gathered, it will then be displayed in the custom cell within the `UITableView`. [image: The plist with the needed data to gather]

Should `Item 0` be a dictionary or array?

So far I have the data being saved as `NSUserDefaults`
[image: Custom cell]

Answer (score 0):

well if you want to use plists like that then keep item 0 as a dictionary... However, I strongly suggest that you use [Core Data](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/cdProgrammingGuide.html) instead of plists to store your data.

Comment: But how will that be possible with adding multiple variables in a core data and then display it in the correct cell and to add cells accordingly to a `UITableview` inside a custom `UITableViewCell`?